# python isfile is not working here

Tags: python-3.x

This is something I can't figure out why not working.
I have purposely set sd_path so that it does not exist, and I am expecting it to go to the "does not exist" exception, and exit the code. But, rather, it is not raising any error, and going to "All Fine"

```
sd_path = "/home/rudra/foo/src/bar"
try:
  os.path.isfile(sd_path)
  try:
    os.access(sd_path, os.X_OK)
  except:
    print("Executable "+sd_path+" does not have suitable permission")
    sys.exit(3)
except:
  print("Executable "+sd_path+" does not exists")
  sys.exit(3)
print("All Fine")
```

Comment: `os.path.isfile` does not raise an exception. It returns boolean value. Same with `os.access`.

Comment: Like @ŁukaszRogalski said, `isfile` doesn't raise exceptions. You'd have to do `open(sd_path).close()` to get the exception you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `if` instead of `try/except`:

```
sd_path = '/home/rudra/foo/src/bar'

if os.path.isfile(sd_path):
    if os.access(sd_path, os.X_OK):
        print('All Fine')
    else:
        print('Executable', sd_path, 'does not have suitable permission')
        sys.exit(3)
else:
    print('Executable', sd_path, 'does not exists')
    sys.exit(3)
```